# How to CSS div 100%

Tags: css

I'm trying to edit a css div to display 100% text on it,

My code is:

```
#categorycontent, .categorycontent {
    display:block;
    line-height:22px;
    height:290px;
    margin:0;
    padding:4px 10px;
    background:#ecebe3;
    border:1px solid #d5d3c7;
}
```

Im trying something like:

```
#categorycontent, .categorycontent{
    display:block;
    line-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:4px 10px;
    background:#ecebe3;
    border:1px solid #d5d3c7;
}
```

but this isnt working.

Im beginner in css, thank you.

EDIT:
Screenshot with height:290px;
http://i45.tinypic.com/359z2ti.png

and screenshot with height:100%;
http://i46.tinypic.com/fwq4q8.png

Comment: you need to better explain what it is you're trying to do. When you say "100% text", do you mean you want all of the text within the `div` to display on the page, but right now some of it is hidden from view? Posting the HTML your working with would also help

Comment: @albi: check sachin code, it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add width as 100%.

```
width:100%;
```

Comment: Ive edited the question, please see 2 screenshots, If I add 100% its not displaying good

Comment: can you please tell me where i can see your screen shots?

Comment: yes. i seen that.. increase padding values. so that your text will be move as per wish.

Answer (score 1):

Your cannot set div height:100% unless body height is 100%

```
 html,body{height:100%}

#categorycontent, .categorycontent{display:block;line-height:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:4px 10px;background:#ecebe3;border:1px solid #d5d3c7;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to display all of the text you put in it, simply set:

`overflow: visible;`

Comment: Ahh, I understand now, I've just added overflow:hidden
to
#categorycontent

and now looks good, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put `height: 100%;` on your `<html>` and `<body>` tags